# Manually infering variable types from a list of examples in string format

Tags: c#, type-inference

I have a `List<string>` of sample data points that I have read from the file. I am looking for a way to infer the most appropriate type for the examples that are in the list. For example imagine the list is initialized like the following:

```
var samples = new List<string>()
    {
        "1",
        "2",
        "2.01"
    };
```

I am looking for a method that accepts this list and returns `System.double`. I am wondering if there is any internal C# method that I can use. my data can be either int, double or a string so I can always try to cast them into int and if it fails cast it into double and if that fails for all element return `System.string`. Is there any easier way of doing it?

Comment: I know nothing about built-in functionality like that.

Comment: Do you want the most appropriate type for each value (int, int, double in your example), or the entire collection (just double here)?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault the entire collection. So double is the type that can hold all three without any problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are supposed to have a single return type, there are ways around this but it would be better to return a string and just have wherever you're calling from handle the string how you want for example.

```
String s=method(samples);
int i;
try
{
     i=s.ToDecimal();
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input string is not a sequence of digits.");
}
catch (OverflowException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number cannot fit in an Int32.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's nothing built-in, but you could write your own:

```
public delegate bool TryParseDelegate<T>(string str, out T value);

public static Tuple<Func<string, bool>, Type> ParsesAs<T>(TryParseDelegate<T> d)
{
    Func<string, bool> f = s =>
    {
        T val;
        return d(s, out val);
    };

    return Tuple.Create(f, typeof(T));
}

public static Type FindBestType(List<string> input)
{
    var parsers = new List<Tuple<Func<string, bool>, Type>>
    {
        ParsesAs<int>(int.TryParse),
        ParsesAs<double>(double.TryParse)
    };

    int i = 0;
    foreach (string str in input)
    {
        while (i < parsers.Count && !parsers[i].Item1(str))
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (i == parsers.Count) break;
    }

    return i == parsers.Count ? typeof(string) : parsers[i].Item2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's only int/double/string you can do something like this. It's not optimized by any means. Just something straightforward that may get you on the right track.

```
public static Type InferType(List<string> samples)
{
    Type stringType= typeof(string);
    Type intType = typeof(int);
    Type doubleType = typeof(double);
    List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.Count; i++)
    {
        int intRepresentation;
        double doubleRepresentation;
        if (int.TryParse(samples[i], out intRepresentation))
        {
            types.Add(intType);
        }
        else if (double.TryParse(samples[i], out doubleRepresentation))
        {
            types.Add(doubleType);
        }
        else
        {
            types.Add(stringType);
            break;
        }
    }

    return types.Any(e => e == stringType) ? stringType :
        types.Any(e => e == doubleType) ? doubleType :
        intType;
}
```